# How to get date part from the current date in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

My File contains Date as Thu 03/26/2015
I need to get output as 03/26/2015 I don't need day part in my date

Comment: What does "My File contains Date" mean? Do you mean you have a text file that contains a string that looks like a date? Please revise your question as it is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score -1):

Use command

**date /t**

Output will gate date only

Comment: `date /t` will give the current date and not read the date from "my file"